# i want to learn adobe flex4. Can anyone help me how to start?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

i want to learn adobe-flex-4. Can anyone help me how to start? I need to learn adobe flex to web development.I tried flex in a week. But i need more help to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Flex Video Trainings by Adobe. They are really top-notch. You can access them [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html).